# How can I hide selected pages from a page list?

Tags: sxa

I have a requirement to render a list of child pages based on a parent item, I plan to use the page list component. One of the requirements asks for the ability to hide selected pages from the page list, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take an approach where you exclude items based on a field used by the search scope/item query.

Create a new base template which has a checkbox to exclude from index.

[image]

On the page template, inherit from the base template.

[image]

On each page that should be exclude, Content Authors can check the box.

[image]

In the scope query you can exclude results based on that checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution; I didn't know it could be done this way, it seems a bit cleaner than mine, cheers.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have implemented similar solution and it works fine lower environments where we are using Solr as search provider but same doesn't work with Azure search. Is there anything we can consider?

Comment: If the question is about the Query I used then it probably means Azure doesn't support the function that Solr does.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by creating a new `Template` that inherits from the `Page` template and contains a `Checkbox` field that you will use to define whether you wish the page to be displayed in the list or not. Page templates are created in `/sitecore/templates/Project/SiteName`

Here's an example I recently created, this template inherits from `Page` and I've added a `Checkbox` field to it.

[image]

In the "Hide from dynamic navigation pod" template item, I've set the default value to `0`.

[image]

Once your new `page template` is complete, you'll now have to set a rule on each of the page list rendering variants in order to control when the page list is displayed.

The checkbox uses a value of `1` to determine `true` so I defined the following rule on each rendering variant wrapper.

[image]

Now, when you tick the "Hide from dynamic navigation pod" box on any page, that page will not be included in any page lists.